# soap_ssl_service_context giving Error 30, gSoap

Tags: c++, ssl, gsoap

I'm making a request to soap_ssl_server_context, I've my certificate **server.pem** in my EXE folder but this request is returning 30 Error code. This error is getting printed on screen as well.

**SOAP 1.2 fault SOAP-ENV:Receiver [no subcode]**

**"SSL/TLS error"**

**Detail: Can't read key file**

```
if( (k = soap_ssl_server_context(&objSoap,
                                        SOAP_SSL_DEFAULT | SOAP_SSL_SKIP_HOST_CHECK,
                                        "server.pem", /* keyfile: required when server must authenticate to clients (see SSL docs on how to obtain this file) */
                                        "abcabc", /* password to read the key file */
                                        NULL, /* optional cacert file to store trusted certificates */
                                        NULL, /* optional capath to directory with trusted certificates */
                                        NULL, /* DH file name or DH key len bits (minimum is 512, e.g. "512") to generate DH param, if NULL use RSA */
                                        NULL, /* if randfile!=NULL: use a file with random data to seed randomness */
                                        "sslserver" /* optional server identification to enable SSL session cache (must be a unique name) */
                                        ) ))
        {
                soap_print_fault(&objSoap,stderr);
                mPtrLogger->logMsg(CF, "", String("--[[[Error Code[[[")+k+"][[[", INFO);
                Terminate(-1, "Certificate files missing...terminating");
        }
```

Comment: Isn't that a cert (certificate) file, as opposed to a key file?

Comment: To clarify, I think you want to pass "server.pem" as the third parameter, not the first.

Comment: Thanks @500-InternalServerError problem got solved by passing server.pem in third parameter.